# Textbox value based on more than one intersection of cells

Tags: excel, vba

What I've tried is that I get the row of a found item then I get a non-empty cell.
My problem is that I cannot figure it out, how to put the second found item into the textbox.
Let's say I have column headers A,B,C,D...

A - - - B - - - C - - - D
1 - - |da| - - - - - - |d0|
2- - -|d1|---|d2| - - - -

So my results now look like this:

D
d0
I'd like to return all related data, but it only displays the last found non-empty in textbox
What I need:

B
da

D
d0

I think it's a tiny but tricky one for me.
Code:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10

Set f = Sheets("db").Range("A:A").Find(What:=UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, 
Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
j = f.Row
If Sheets("db").Cells(j, i) <> "" Then
TextBox8.Value = Sheets("db").Cells(1, i).Value & ":" & vbCrLf & Sheets("db").Cells(j, i) & vbCrLf
End If
Next
```

Comment: I see multiple issues in the code that you had provided. The find is not dependent on the For loop as it doesn't use the "i" value. It only searches the first column for a value provided through TextBox1. So it can be outside the loop, resulting in j being a constant inside the For loop. Do you think, this what you have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can move the Find outside the For loop. And make it as below, with the TextBox8 filled with a string made inside the loop.

```
Dim i As Integer

Set f = Sheets("db").Range("A:A").Find(What:=UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, 
Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
j = f.Row

sValue = ""
For i = 1 To 10
    If Sheets("db").Cells(j, i) <> "" Then
        sValue = sValue & Sheets("db").Cells(1, i).Value & ":" & vbCrLf & Sheets("db").Cells(j, i) & vbCrLf
    End If
Next

TextBox8.value = sValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the found values as a string.
Go through the row cell by cell and add the found values to the string.

When you are done you put the TextBox8.Value = *your string*